# How to show toast message when click tab?

Tags: java, android

I searched this question many time but I couldn't find a solution. I have a Tab Menu in my application. I want to show some text with toast when click another tab.

**MainActivity.java;**
[MainActivity.java](http://textuploader.com/d6phr)

**Page1Fragment.java;**
[Fragment.java](http://textuploader.com/d6pho)

What can I do about it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your MainActivity' onCreate method add this one at the bottom

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(Tab tab) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab clicked", 
   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother it's working.

getActivity(), don't working in this example. Must to change with=> MainActivity.this

Comment: Glad it helped :)